# Any free download manager for Linux compatible with Chromium

Tags: linux, google-chrome, download-manager, chromium

Right now I have no other choice but to open the desired link in Firefox and then download it with DownThemAll!

It would be great to find an alternative to DownThemAll! for Chrome.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Chrome/Chromium's built-in download manager works well for small numbers of files.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in one?

Comment: downthemall is a download accelerator, it splits downloads in several parts and is very fast...

Answer (score 0):

The only one I know of is http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2010/12/finally-download-accelerator-for-linux.html

but I would recommend using wget or torrents for large files.

To read about linux download accelerators(not for chromium) http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-download-managers-available-in-ubuntu.html